# view only user group for django admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

Greetings
I am trying to find a way to implement "view only user group" for selected models at the django admin site. In details, when a selected user of a group logs in, he/she can only browse and see allowed model entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write decorator to allow access to certain model for a member of a specific group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same.

I've seen a reference to a patch that claims to add this feature:

http://www.alextreme.org/drupal/?q=django-view-permissions-patch

Here's another approach:

http://gremu.net/blog/2010/django-admin-read-only-permission/

(I have not yet tried it, but will report back here if I do.)

Note this page on the philosophy behind django-admin not providing this on its own:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/